# Multiple HostedServices with common base class

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to set up multiple hosted services that all share some base functionality, but differ in some configuration that they use to set things up (like connection strings, urls, values, or whatever). I would like to achieve something like this in `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddHostedService<CustomHostedService1>(config =>
{
    config.Value = 1234;
});
services.AddHostedService<CustomHostedService2>(config =>
{
    config.Value = 5678;
});
```

The base class and derived classes would look something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    public MyConfigObject Config { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ConfigureBaseClass(Config);
        DoWork();
    }

    private void ConfigureBaseClass(MyConfigObject config)
    {
        // Use config to do something
    }
    
    public abstract void DoWork();
}

public class CustomHostedService1 : BaseHostedService
{
    private readonly ISomeService1 _someService;

    public CustomHostedService1(ISomeService1 someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }
    
    public override void DoWork()
    {
        // Do some work here
        _someService.DoWork();
    }
}

public class CustomHostedService2 : BaseHostedService
{
    private readonly ISomeService2 _someService;
    private readonly ILogger<CustomHostedService2> _logger;

    public CustomHostedService2(ILogger<CustomHostedService2> logger, ISomeService2 someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
       _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override void DoWork()
    {
        // Do some work here
        _someService.DoWork();
    }
}
```

What would be a good pattern to achieve this? Note that the two derived classes might have different dependencies.

Comment: What is the problem here? Both derived classes once added should work as intended.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to pass different configuration to the two instances of the base class in the Program.cs

Comment: @Nkosi see above ☝️